# Деформация текст

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите, как можно сверстать такой вот текст? На ум приходит только transform, но это не совсем то, что нужно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С помощью **svg** можно создать такой эффект

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22884389/6452878